# const char* вопрос

Tags: c++

Если для const int* нельзя присвоить литерал, а также изменить уже присвоенное значение l-value (логично),то почему для const char* можно присвоить литерал, да еще и изменить в последствии значение? Хотя пишут, что меняется не значение, а переназначается указатель, в таком случае мы цепляем наш указатель к загаданной строке "example" из всей Вселенной? Тогда почему адрес выводится один и тот же на выходе?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int value1{5};
    int value2{6};
    int* value3=&value1;
    std::cout<<"&value3="<<value3<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"\t&value1="<<&value1<<'\n';
    value3=&value2;
    std::cout<<"&value3="<<value3<<'\n';
    const char* a{"stroka1"};
    a="abcd";
    std::cout<<"&a="<<&a<<'\n';
    a="efg";
    std::cout<<"&a="<<&a<<'\n';
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы выводите адрес *переменной*, а не *содержащийся в переменной*. Переменная на своем месте - с чего ее адресу меняться?! Будьте тогда последовательны и при выводе `std::cout<<"&value3="<<value3<<'\n';` перед `value3` пишите `&`!

Comment: `почему для const char* можно присвоить литерал` Потому что строковый литерал — это `static` массив из `N` элементов типа `const char`. И в указателе сохраняется адрес первого элемента такого массива.

Comment: Строковые литералы - lvalue, живущие все время жизни программы, поэтому у них можно взять адрес. Все остальные литералы - prvalue. *"изменить уже присвоенное значение l-value"* Вот это вообще не понял.

Comment: строковый литерал это lvalue, это я упустил.

Answer (score 1):

Константность определяет тип на что указывает переменная, а не само его значение *(указатель)*. Примеры объявления константности :

```
// указатель на константные буквы
const char * a {"stroka1"};

// то же самое
char const * a {"stroka2"};

// a - константный указатель на буквы,
// которые можно менять, но сам указатель - нет
char s [ ] = "stroka3" ;
char * const a = s ;

// константный указатель на константные буквы
char const * const a {"stroka4"};
```

Теперь адрес `& a` - выдаёт адрес, где хранится значение **переменной**, а не само его значение.

```
char const * a {"stroka"};

// a - имеет тип указателя на буквы
//  char const *

// & a - это адрес указателя на переменную которая тоже указатель
//  char const * *
```

С типом `int *` - то же самое.

```
// переменная целочисленного типа
int i ;

// адрес переменной i
int * pi = & i ;

// & i - адрес переменной целого числа с типом
//  int *

// & pi - адрес переменной с типом указателя на указатель, имеющее тип
//  int * *
```

Comment: не пойму, почему в случае с const int*/int* можно через cout видеть новые адреса указателя, а в случае const char* нет? и почему если инту* присвоить динамический массив, то распечатается 1я цифра, а в случае чара вся строка, cout перегрузили так для удобства?

Comment: да, перегрузка `operator<< (char const *)` так работает. Помогает так : `cout << (void*)a`

Comment: @user498394 `cout` по-особому обрабатывает указатели на `char` (печатает как строки). *"если инту* присвоить динамический массив, то распечатается 1я цифра, а в случае чара вся строка"* А вот это неправда.

Comment: в gcc 9.2.0 попробовал, так и есть. const char* печатает всю строку, а const int* первое число из массива.

Comment: @user498394 Пример кода в студию. Такое может быть только если перед указателем на число вы поставили `*`, а перед указателем на строку нет.

Comment: ясное дело, "cout<<mass" ничего бы хорошего не выдал

Comment: @user498394 Я к тому, что странно этому удивляться, ведь вы с разными типами обращаетесь по-разному. Если сделать то же самое со строкой - увидите первую букву, как и ожидалось.